# How can I read all arguments with the VBS-SAPI-VOICE?

Tags: vbscript, sapi

I want to create a program, that automaticly reads all
start-arguments. This is what I end with after some hours
of researching and debugging but it still not working.
(I'm not very experienced in VBScript.)
The Error Message is something like "Instruction expected" or "statement expected"
I dont know whats the right translation.(I use the German Version. The original Errormessage is: "Anweisung erwartet")

```
Private Sub Say()
Set VOICE = createobject("sapi.spvoice")
Set Args = WScript.Arguments
Count = 0
While(count > Args.Count)
    VOICE.speak(WScript.Arguments(count))
    count = count + 1
End While
End Sub

Say()
```

Have someone an idea?
I hope you understood what I mean. (My English is awful)

Comment: Use a `for - Each` loop. `For each thing in Wscript.Arguments` `Msgbox thing` `next`.

Comment: @Mark Can you give me the code? I'm still getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [this](https://ss64.com/vb/arguments.html) you can write something like that :

```
Set VOICE = createobject("sapi.spvoice")
' Store the arguments in a variable:
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments
If objArgs.Count = 0 Then 
    Wscript.Echo "Missing parameters"
    VOICE.Speak "Missing parameters"
End If

' Display all command-line arguments
For Each strArg in objArgs
  WScript.Echo strArg
  VOICE.Speak strArg
Next
```